# Difference between sarq and shrq

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, bit-shift

Name: Value

%rdi: 0x6

%rax: 0x4

What is the difference between sarq and shrq?

If I had sarq $1, %rdi how would this value look?
What does shrq %rdi do?

Comment: This looks like assembler. Care to say which processor?

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm puzzled as to why you tagged this question [tag:x86-16]. I'll change this into [tag:x86-64].

Comment: @SepRoland: Thanks, probably a typo / misclick on a wrong auto-complete option.  I'm pretty sure I didn't intend to tag x86-16, but thanks for double-checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sarq` is arithmetic right shift for quadword, and `shrq` is logical right shift for quadword. The difference is that arithmetic shift will fill the vacant bits with the leftmost bit (aka the sign bit) while the logical right shift will just fill them with 0.

For positive numbers, their behavior is the same. For negative numbers, their behavior is totally different.

For example, assume `%rax = 16 (0x0000 0000 0000 0010)`. Both `sar $4, %rax` and `shrq $4, %rax` will set the `%rax` to 1 (`0x0000 0000 0000 0001`).

Now if `%rax = -16 (0xffff ffff ffff fff0)`. `sar $4, %rax` will set `%rax` to -1 (`0xffff ffff ffff ffff`) while `shr $4, %rax` will set `%rax` to 1152921504606846975 (`0x0fff ffff ffff ffff`).

To use which instruction depends on the data type and what you want to do. The C `>>` operator uses `sar` for signed data types and `shr` for unsigned ones.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that sarq works on signed integers, shrq works on unsigned. Basically if the highest bit in the integer is set, sarq will shift in 1's (otherwise zeros). shrq will only ever shift in zeros. You can easily see what they do with some simple C.

```cpp
int main()
{
  int val = -4;

  // signed arithmetic shift
  int rval = val >> 1;

  // will print -2
  std::cout << rval << std::endl;

  unsigned uval = -4;

  // unsigned logical shift
  unsigned ruval = uval >> 1;

  // will print 0x7FFFFFFE
  std::cout << ruval << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: it's actually implementation-defined whether `int >>` is arithmetic or logical.  Actually just that the "result is implementation-defined" for right shifts of negative values.  But all sane C implementations use arithmetic ([Signed right shift: which compiler use logical shift](//stackoverflow.com/q/6487918)); e.g. the GNU C dialect of C even guarantees arithmetic 2's complement right shift = sign-extension.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html)

Comment: But anyway, an x86 DeathStation 9000 could compile your code to use logical right shift in both cases without violating the ISO C standard.  Of course you meant using a sane compiler that would actually emit `sar` and `shr` when expected.